# Xpath problem- cant locate the class

Tags: automated-testing

```
@When("I click on sign in again")
    public void i_click_on_sign_in_again() {
    WebElement signin1  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='uitk-button uitk-button-medium uitk-button-fullWidth uitk-button-has-text uitk-button-primary']"));
        signin1.click();
    }
```

Xpath couldn't locate the element. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Share the error message that you get while running this piece of code. That will help better to understand the issue. Otherwise the code: WebElement signin1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='uitk-button uitk-button-medium uitk-button-fullWidth uitk-button-has-text uitk-button-primary']"));
   signin1.click(); is working just fine. I tried it by recreating the anchor tag in a local HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

**Above xpath not working because there a new line after button and 'primary' is in next line**

**1. if only and only want to find via class attribute then:**

> //a[contains(@class,'uitk-button uitk-button-medium uitk-button-fullWidth uitk—button-has-text uitk—button-')][contains(@class,'primary')]

OR

> //a[contains(@class,'uitk-button uitk-button-medium uitk-button-fullWidth uitk—button-has-text uitk—button-')]

2. **Try finding with text:**

> xpath = "//a[contains(text(),'Sign in')]

OR

> xpath = "//a[contains(@href,'/user/signin')]

Comment: The CSS doesn't have an actual newline character. That's just how the HTML will be displayed in the console or in an IDE with word wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Many companies provide automation testing services and this issue is very commonly faced by automation engineers.
Below are the solutions to solve the problem:

Try finding with below xpath:

xpath = "//a[text()='Sign in']

Another way is through link text:

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in"));

Sometimes if the page does not load properly then also element could not be located. For this scenario, you can add some wait.